# What is a recommended Python Library for InfoPath XML?

Tags: library, python, xml

I am looking for a Python library that will allow me to parse an InfoPath XML file, then manipulate it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to add more details.  As it stands, your question is asking for opinions.

Comment: Infopath uses a lot of different XML file formats. Which one(s) in particular are you trying to parse?

Comment: All Python XML parsers can parse any valid XML. Do you have any requirements that are specific to InfoPath? If yes, please explain them, thanks! :-)